# Auto switching between multiple versions of referenced assemblies

Tags: .net, reflection, reference, emgucv, early-binding

I need to reference EmguCV from a solution containing one C# WinForms project.

There are four versions of the same library i.e. x86 vand x64, each with and without GPU support. The library requires references to EmguCV's managed DLLs as well as OpenCV's unmanaged DLLs. Copying the correct unmanaged version to the `[Bin]` folder is easy enough through post-build events.

I want to be able to switch between the managed references easily through code. Maybe something like the following:

```
public enum EnumEmguCvTarget
{
    None, // Do not use EmguCv
    EmguCvTargetTbb86, // Target EmguCv for x86 without GPU.
    EmguCvTargetGpu86, // Target EmguCv for x86 with GPU.
    EmguCvTargetTbb64, // Target EmguCv for x64 without GPU.
    EmguCvTargetGpu64, // Target EmguCv for x64 with GPU.
}

public EnumEmguCvTarget EmguCvTarget
{ get { return (EnumEmguCvTarget.EmguCvTargetGpu64); } }
```

Since I am referencing these assemblies at compile time (not late binding), is there a way I can programatically switch between versions based on the value of `[EmguCvTarget]`?

Comment: That wouldn't work, a dll that references and uses an x64 library cannot load or reference an x86 library at the same time. What you could do is create an interface project (AnyCPU) and then load these assemblies through reflection, cast to the interface and use as if nothing has happened.

Comment: @jessehouwing: Thanks. Could you please elaborate on the `interface project`. Also, if I resort to reflection, is there a way to still have Intellisense work like early-binding?

Comment: Yes that's the whole idea of the interface :)

Comment: @jessehouwing: If I understand you correctly, I would need to create interfaces to all objects in the EmguCV library! That is a lot of work for what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Create interfaces for the objects you're using in `EmguCv` and place these in a separate `AnyCpu` project. If there is no common interface for these objects, or when you cannot alter these objects, you'll need to create your own wrapper objects for these classes. It is important that these interfaces are defined in their own assembly, since you'll be referencing this assembly from all your own code.

```
 public interface IEmguCv{ /* methods and proeprties */ }
 public class EmguCv : IEmguCv { }
```

Now in your existing application, use Reflection or `Activator.CreateInstance` to load the correct assembly:

```
 // which assembly to load depends on your configuration
 Assembly emguAssembly = Assembly.Load("EmguX64");
 Type emguType = emguAssembly.GetType("EmguCvClassYouAddedInterfacesTo");
 IEmguCv object = (IEmguCv)Activator.CreateInstance(emguType);
```

From here you can use the IEmguCv interface, which will provide you with strong binding, IntelliSense and all the other things you'd expect, but you will be able to load the assembly dynamically based on the context you're under.

Should you need to call a non-default constructor on the EmguCv object, then you can either use the [`Activator.CreateInstance(Type, Object[], Object[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b0ww1we.aspx) overload, or call the constructor through [`Type.GetConstructor(Type[]).Invoke()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h93ya84h.aspx).

You could also use a library such as Unity or NInject once you have an interface defined, so that you can use these DI containers to do the reflection work for you.